# How can I remove files based on the time they were created?

Tags: linux, file, ubuntu, filesystems, delete-file

I was copying a directory, and I ended up spitting out its contents in a shared, home directory. I want to delete all these files. They all were "created" in the shared directory at the same time, so how can I filter these files out? Going one by one is not feasible. How would I remove them all in one command using rm command with some sort of "time created" parameter on Ubuntu?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't have enough points to add comment on your question thats why I have to add answer to it.

There is  no parameter in 'ls' command for creation time.

visit this link for help on same issue.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/23688/best-way-to-list-100-first-files-in-a-directory-sorted-by-time

Comment: There is no parameter in 'ls' command for creation time? The `-l` parameter?

Comment: ls -l command doesn't print creation time.  6 , 7 and 8th column print the month date and time of last change made to file.

Answer (score -1):

Try this command:

```
 rm -vi `ls -lh | sed -n '/Oct 18/p' | awk '{print $9}'`
```

You can change the expression in sed to make anything you want.